# Android app custom web service authentication using HttpPost does not stick

Tags: android, http-post

In my application I'm fetching data in JSON format from a web service (Yii PHP site acting as a REST service) that requires authentication.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(login_url);
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(name, pass);
post.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(credentials, "UTF-8", false));
```

All methods are executed by a single instance of `DefaultHttpClient` with use of subclassed `AsyncTask`.

Authentication works fine, but fetching data from another URL gets authentication fail (custom message in internal service format).

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(service_url);
client.execute(post);
```

Trying to figure out what's the problem I've checked for answers and tested some of them.

I've managed to establish that `CookieStorage` in `DefaultHttpClient` instance actually receives and holds Cookies, after first call there are two, one of them is `PHPSESSID` and it's not expired. Second one appears to be some encoded stuff and it's expiration date seems to be creation time, because it's already expired when I receive it.

If you have any thoughts on this issue, please comment. I've hit a deadend with searching and trying out things that worked for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there was no problem with my code, but the service had an error. Thanks for viewing this question and to [@Joël](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975214/jo%c3%abl-salamin) for formatting this for me. Kudos